# How to prevent XStream from adding the class=null attribute to xml

Tags: java, xml, xstream

We updated xstream to the latest version 1.4.20, when we serialize to xml it started adding class=null to elements if the call. attributes is null. it did not have this in the output for earlir versions
ex.

```
  <last class="null" />
  <first class="null" />
  <middle class="null" />
  <dob class="null" />
```

We need this to print either as  or  ....

is there an option to disable adding this class attribute to our xml. Hope someone has a solution.

im blocked
omitfField will not work for us
i can write code to remove it from the string but this is not a clean solution